# ImportError: No module named pyscreenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshot, python-module, ubuntu-17.04

I have created I python program which makes 100 screenshots, and saves them on a folder called `img` inside the OS folder `Documents`. It worked perfectly fine in my Linux Ubuntu, it did the 100 screenshots and saved them in the directory I wanted. Now, I created a new Linux user in the same Virtual Machine, and I ran the same python script. 
It gives me this error: `ImportError: No module named pyscreenshot`
I have tried many times. It works in my other user, although in the new one it keeps giving me error. Is there any reason for this?
Thanks. The code is below:

```
import os
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def photos(num):
    for n in range(num):
        s = str(n)
        a = "../Documents/img/s" + s + ".png"
        # grab fullscreen
        im = ImageGrab.grab()

        # save image file

        im.save(a)

    return True
```

Quick note: I am calling the function `photos()` from another file using `import screenshot` (the file is called 'screenshot.py')

Comment: is `pyscreenshot` installed for the new user ?

Comment: try with `pip install pyscreenshot --user`

Comment: Don't worry I already got the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to install `pyscreenshot` for your user

```
pip install pyscreenshot
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the answers provided above don't work, try using

```
sudo -H pip install pyscreenshot
```